# mail MIME-Version and Content-Type not setting header - Mail Behavior Different from Ubuntu 14.04 vs Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, email, mail

I recently copied over scripts from an Ubuntu 14.04 server to an Ubuntu 20.04 server.  Some of my scripts do NOT appear to work as they did before on the older Ubuntu 14.04 server now that they're running on Ubuntu 20.04.  One such script uses the mail command, and for some reason, I get differences with the email that is ultimately sent by the server.  The same mail command run from an Ubuntu 14.04 server versus an Ubuntu 20.04 server produces noticeable differences when running a mail command similar to the one below:

```
mail -s "Report" -A "/home/path1/pic1.jpg" -A "/home/path1/pic2.jpg" -A "/home/path1/pic3.jpg" -A "/home/path1/pic4.jpg -a "From: noreply@someemail.com" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-Type: text/plain" "test@test.com" <<< "This text will be attached as a file named noname.txt with empty message contents in Ubuntu 20.04 rather than being plain text as the message content like it did in Ubuntu 14.04

--------
Thanks
Testing Bot"
```

In Ubuntu 20.04, the above mail command outputs the following errors / messages in the terminal:

```
mail: MIME-Version: not setting header
mail: Content-Type: not setting header
```

Why is that?  In Ubuntu 14.04, the mail command produces no "not setting header" messages and works as intended.  The email sent from an Ubuntu 14.04 server has plain text content as the message body contents where as the email sent from an Ubuntu 20.04 server has the message "This text will be attached..." attached as a file named noname.txt with no message body contents (empty).

Anyone know why?  How do I get this mail command to produce an email similar to the way Ubuntu 14.04 would send it?

Comment: Confirming the exact same behavior coming from Ubuntu 16.04. Sending only the message part without the attachment part works fine and also v.v.

Comment: It should be a bug in mailutils 3.7 For more infos see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470553/behavior-of-sending-email-with-text-and-attachment-changed-in-ubuntu-20-04-for-m

Answer (score 0):

workaround is using -M or -- mime and also content-type="text/plain"

mailutil Bug workaround Link: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22

https://superuser.com/questions/1166752/cant-send-email-with-html-body-and-attachment

Note that --content-type is a positional option referring to all following attachments (if there are more than one) and the last value specified is then also used for the message body (this is why it's changed again at the end).